# What was the point of the switch?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, a-memory-of-light

At the end of *A Memory of Light*,

> Rand switches bodies with Moridin.

What was the point of this switch? Won't the new form attract unwanted attention too?

> Since Rand/Moridin can adjust his appearance using the *mask of mirrors*, was this simply an attempt to give Rand a new hand? I'm guessing that his tainted wounds would now heal OK (in his original body).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The point of the switch is twofold, I think.

**Anonymity**

The switch is only known to a very small number of people, while everyone else thinks that

> Rand is dead.

Additionally, almost no one left alive

> knows what Moridin actually looks like,

so no one will recognize the new form, and will just consider him to be a random person. Since

> Rand no longer "channels" to channel, he should never be "detected" doing anything unusual, and

he can now go about complete unrecognized by the rest of the world.

**Prophecy**

One of the key aspects of the *Prophecies of the Dragon* that's been quoted at us for a long time was that

> Rand had to die.

It was pretty explicit in other forms of prophecy as well, such as Min's visions and Egwene's dreaming. By the end of the series,

> Rand *did* die, or his body did, it was just Moridin in the body at the time.

That allowed prophecies and visions to be fulfilled, just not in the way that everyone expected.

Answer (score 4):

> I think the point of the switch was to let Rand enjoy living again.  To everyone (except maybe his friends) hes not Rand, hes the Dragon Reborn.  People would have obligations and expectations of him, and given all that he had to give up to defeat the Dark One, he can now avoid all that and simply live and enjoy obscurity.